# R variables often not being recognized

Tags: r

I am new to R, and just trying to get some basic examples up and running. However, I am finding that even if I try to perform simple assignment statements, often the resulting variables are not recognized in the R workspace. For example:

If I specify:

```
Wingcrd <- c(59, 55, 53.5, 55, 52.5, 57.5, 53, 55)
```

and then type `Wingcrd` in the R console, I correctly see:

```
Wingcrd
[1] 59.0 55.0 53.5 55.0 52.5 57.5 53.0 55.0
```

However, if I simply specify a second variable as follows within my script:

```
Wingcrd <- c(59, 55, 53.5, 55, 52.5, 57.5, 53, 55)
Tarsus <- c(22.3, 19.7, 20.8, 20.3, 20.8, 21.5, 20.6, 21.5)
```

and then try to access both variables in the R workspace, I get:

```
Wingcrd
[1] 59.0 55.0 53.5 55.0 52.5 57.5 53.0 55.0

Tarsus
```

> Error: object 'Tarsus' not found

This 'object not found' error continues to occur for a variety of contexts, e.g. when I attempt to read in a file using read.table(), etc.

The script that I am running is saved in the same directory that is specified as the overall R workspace, so I am not sure what is going on here.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Are you sure you didn't have an error when you defined `Tarsus`? Are you sure you are spelling it the same way (capitalization matters!)? Are you sure you *actually ran* the `Tarsus` definition code, you didn't just add it to a script file without running it? At any point you can use `ls()` to see the objects defined in your workspace.

Comment: Same here. Works fine for me too.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful responses!

I was under the mistaken impression that I could save and run my script without highlighting each individual line to be run, and indeed, the second line of the script was not being run. I will keep this in mind moving forward...

Answer (score -1):

If it is within a R-script, try ending the first variable with ";"
like

```
Wingcrd <- c(59, 55, 53.5, 55, 52.5, 57.5, 53, 55);
Tarsus <- c(22.3, 19.7, 20.8, 20.3, 20.8, 21.5, 20.6, 21.5);
other functions and lines here
```

This might get that working.

Refer to @Gregor 's comment. Are you really sure everything ran without error?
Suggestion: Use RStudio!

Comment: Thanks for your input, Shubhradeep. FYI, I determined that for the particular R editor I'm using, unlike most editors I'm accustomed to, saving a script and then running it does not run all of the code in the script; I need to manually highlight all of the code that I need to run. When I do this, my code runs as expected, and the variables are accessible in the workspace.